# How to Kill threads that are present in Controller in its model (Ruby 2.1.2 on Rails 3.2.13)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller **RamsController** in that I have this method

```
def check_status
   @ram = Ram.find(params[:id])
   if @ram.workflow == "start"
      thread_status = Thread.new do
         thread.current[:name] = "thread_check_status"
         @ram.check_status!
         ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
      end
      @ram.thread_check_status = thread_status
   end
  render json: { status: "success" }
end
```

I have a model code like this

```
class Ram < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :thread_check_status 

  def self.kill_threads
    self.thread_check_status.kill
  end

  def exception_handler(exception)
   if exception == "exited by user"
     self.kill_threads
   end
  end
```

Whenever an exception is caught it will go to the exception_handler method in the model. 
And now, I'm trying to kill the thread when the exception is caught  so I tried to assign the thread to the variable  `@ram.thread_check_status = thread_status` So I created a method `def self.kill_threads`  in the model to kill the threads and called that method in `def excpetion_handle` method.

But, it is not working I think I assigned the thread to the variable in a wrong way `@ram.thread_check_status = thread_status`

Please suggest me how to kill the threads associated with `@ram` **id** in the model.

And I have two more methods in **RamsController** with two more threads and I'm trying kill those threads too.

Comment: keep in mind your `@ram` instance variable only exists for the duration of the single request. So you either need some global variable for thread references, or perhaps store PID in the database.

Comment: Yes, the PID is stored in the database @maxple

Comment: Youre setting thread check status as an attrivute on an instance and attempting to read it as an attribute of the class

Comment: Also you need to use update or save to persist the instance attrivute. Just using = doesnt work

Comment: Is there any way that I can read that particular thread in the model ? @maxple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with a solution like this.
Firstly, in the controller I set the thread variable with a name and value like this

```
def check_status
   @ram = Ram.find(params[:id])
   if @ram.workflow == "start"
      Thread.new do
```

> `Thread.current.thread_variable_set(:thread_name, @ram.id)`#This will set the thread value to ram_id

```
         @ram.check_status!
         ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
      end
      @ram.thread_check_status = thread_status
   end
  render json: { status: "success" }
end
```

So in the model I listed all the threads available and killed the thread which is associated with ram_id, thread_name

```
class Ram < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :thread_check_status 



  def exception_handler(exception)
```

> `Thread.list.each do |thr|`
>
> `if thr.thread_variable_get(:thread_name) == self.id`
>
> `thr.kill`
>
> `end`
>
> `end`

```
   if exception == "exited by user"
     self.kill_threads
   end
end
```